# NodeJS download csv file to buffer

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv

I'm tying to download a small csv and I need to store it in a variable before process:

```
var http = require('http');

var csvData;
var request = http.get('http://url', function(response) {
  response.pipe(csvData);
});
request.end();
```

`response.pipe()` only works with file stream, how can i store my response to `csvData` var?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create listener for `data` and `end` events:

```
var http = require('http');

var csvData = '';
var request = http.get('http://url', function(response) {
    response.on('data', function(chunk) {
        csvData += chunk;
    });
    response.on('end', function() {
        // prints the full CSV file
        console.log(csvData);
    });
});
```

Comment: `csvData` is a string, OP asked to download the file in a `Buffer`